# Selling someone else's product on your site

Tags: html, shopify

What methods are there for obtaining a list of another store's products so you can offer it on your own site? Do you need to have some kind of affiliation? For example "Let us order pizza for you. You choose the type of pizza and from where you want it, and check out through us, and we will get the pizza to you!" And for example list pizza places to do so from. How would I accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: If you are asking if you can drop ship items from other stores; yes you can. It is the whole premise of what the majority of shopify stores do. As for can you automate this process? Look into data scraping as most sites like shopify won't let you gain access to that information. (For good reason too).

Comment: Sounds good, thank you! Yeah I'm talking mostly about something like a distribution site. That lists different distributors and their product offerings

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your categories. Before asking all the questions like "Do you need to have some kind of affiliation?" you need to research the legalities in your area.